# Handle textDidChange Method in NSTextView

Tags: events, keydown, nstextview

I want trigger the event if the text is changing in my NSTextView. Is there a way to trigger that directly from the NSTextView or I have to create a custom Class for the NSTextView?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
  ----do stuff here----  
    NSLog(@"text typed");  
}
```

add the method to your code...enough